# rails test error with devise application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

When i has added devise module to my rails application my tests thwors error

```
 73) Error:
test_should_update_task(TasksControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:56:in `current_user'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:52:in `user_signed_in?'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:53:in `user_signed_in?'
    /home/razor/work/judgement/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___67557477041607610_29516700'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    /home/razor/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'

93 tests, 36 assertions, 0 failures, 73 errors, 0 skips
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (73): [/usr/bin/ruby19 -I"lib:test" -I"/usr/lib64...]>
```

where the application.html.erb is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Judgement</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <% if user_signed_in? then %>
            <%= link_to "You are #{current_user.email}", edit_user_registration_path %>
            <%= link_to "Exit", destroy_user_session_path, { :method => :delete,
                                                             :confirm => "Are you sure"} %>
            <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %>
            <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %>
            <% end %>
        </nav>
        <%= yield %>
        <div class="notice">
            <%= notice %>
        </div>
        <div class="alert">
            <%= alert %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So this looks like error because "user_signed_in?" helper. But i can not understand what is the point of error.

I am not very familiar with all Rails magic.

UPD: SOLVED

I was must to add

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

to my test/test_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use this functions : https://gist.github.com/989413. Your tests will be more isolated. In your can, you can just stub like this : `helper.stub(:user_signed_in?) {false}`. The function user_signed_in? should return true or false as you want.

There is a similare question here : [Testing helpers in Rails 3 with Rspec 2 and Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663897/testing-helpers-in-rails-3-with-rspec-2-and-devise)

**Edit for Test::Unit**

It think you should redefine a method to mock with Test::Unit. Something like this :

```
module Devise
  module Controllers
    module Helpers    
      def user_signed_in?
        true #Return false if you want
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it. See this page : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29. There is a part for your problem in the end.

Comment: I edited my post for Test::Unit. I'm not sure. You can use mocha for Test::Unit if it doesn't works.

Comment: I just needed to add
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
to the test/test_helper.rb as written in documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this for view specs in rspec, you'll want to stub it on `view`, not `helper`.

```
allow(view).to receive(:user_signed_in?).and_return(true)
```

[Source in rspec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-view-spec-that-stubs-a-helper-method)